# Calling an Objective C Class with Swift Code

Tags: objective-c, swift

In my swift app I am trying to use an existing Objective-C class that I found to adapt for the purposes of Swift in Xcode 8.  The header I am using isn't adding values to put into the class when using my `ViewController`.

The header code is

```
import "DoublesMatrix.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#ifndef PolynomialRegression_h
#define PolynomialRegression_h

@interface PolynomialRegression : NSObject {
+ (NSMutableArray *) regressionWithXValues: (NSMutableArray *)ovals AndYValues: (NSMutableArray *) yvals PolynomialDegree: (int) p;
@end

#endif /* PolynomialRegression_h */
```

While this is acceptable in Objective-C it is not available in swift, and when I attempt to call it, it says "argument passed to call that takes no arguments".

Comment: Show how you're trying to call the function - you realize it's a class function, right?  So you'll need to call it by saying `PolynomialRegression.regressionWithXValues...`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html